# Is wp_login_form secure enough?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, security

Is the `wp_login_form()` function in WP secure enough?

I see there are no nonce fields.

I managed to add a nonce field, but I'm not sure whether WP will consider it or if it is just yet another field in the form.

Is it secure enough or should I proceed further with custom coding?